# Pass Django CSRF token to Angular with CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY

Tags: angularjs, django, cookies, csrf, django-csrf

In Django, when the `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` setting is set to True, the CSRF cookie gains the httponly flag, which is desirable from a security perspective, but breaks the standard angular solution of adding this cookie to the httpProvider like so:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

Through Django 1.9, there was a workaround where you could just pass the cookie directly to the app by putting this in the template:

```
<script>
    window.csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
```

And putting this in the angular app:

```
angularApp.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRFToken"] = window.csrf_token;
}]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for single page angular apps in Django 1.10+ since the CSRF cookie changes after every request.  How do you make post requests from Angular to Django 1.10+ with the `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` setting on?
**NB:** Disabling CSRF protection is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django has a documented solution for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true).  Any Javascript can get the CSRF token from the DOM even if CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY is enabled as long as the CSRF token is in the DOM.

**Step 1**: I add a tag to let Django middleware put csrf token to the DOM

```html
# Django put CSRF token to DOM
{% csrf_token %}
```

**Step 2**: Implement an HttpInterceptor to get csrf from DOM

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DjangoCSRFInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = (
      document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]') as HTMLInputElement
    ).value;
    return httpRequest.clone({ headers: httpRequest.headers.set('X-CSRFToken, token) });
  }
}
```

**Step 3**: Put HttpInterceptor to your Angular module providers

```js
providers: [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: DjangoCSRFInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question was answered well in this discussion.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/nXjfLd8ba5k

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27534

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY does not provide any additional security for single page apps. Some people reccomended this solution

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
if (csrftoken === null) {
    csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    if (csrftoken === null) {
        console.log('No csrf token');
    }
}
```

however either or if you are exposing csrftoken for your app restfully nothing stops the malcious user from taking it and using it as well. If you are running a single page app you might as well set CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False, As per comment bellow:

> Gavin Wahl     5/4/15
>
> > How so? You cannot just ajax-fetch stuff from different domains.
>
> I'm talking about a single domain. Injected javascript on a page that
>   doesn't contain the CSRF token can fetch a different page on the same
>   domain to get it.
>
> > If you already injected javascript onto the victims page (XSS) there is no need to fetch the CSRF token, you already got greater control.
>
> Well, the HttpOnly flag is intended to reduce the damage an attacker
>   can do once the already can inject javascript. But I agree -- hiding
>   the CSRF token from javascript doesn't increase security in any way,
>   but the documentation implies it does. I want to make it clear in the
>   documentation that this setting has no meaningful effect.
>
> > If you still think you have a valid attack vector there, please send it to secu...@djangoproject.com and add a bit more explanation.
>
> There is no attack vector. This is just about misleading
>   documentation.

Comment: To summarize: "You can't.  Don't use the CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY setting"